# Select2 not working on Android

Tags: android, jquery-select2

**jQuery Select2** dropdowns do not work on **Android**.
The behaviour is quit awkward since it just jumps screen when pressing the dropdown.

It works fine on iOS and any browser on desktop.

any ideas on why this might happen or how can I debug this?
a sample page [here](https://www.printello.de/broschuere/klebebindung.html)